# bsts posterior distributions

Tags: r

Some basic questions re bsts - not how to run the programme but what it is actually computing. I cannot get the answers by typing bsts, which leads to Call("analysis_common_r_fit_bsts_model_"...) which I cannot access and might not understand if I could. I've tried r-help and emailing the package maintainer. I hope one of you can help or point me to the answer.

For the gaussian case with no regressors and a local level model, the code below appears to mimic bsts. It produces graphs similar to the model plot, and confirms the relationship between the output of sigma.level and sigma.obs with the state contribution. However, a direct approach to the posterior distribution for these sigmas does not match the bsts output. I'm not sure if it's a simple error, if I misunderstand SdPrior or if the differences involve mcmc...

```
setwd("/home/greg/Documents/rwork/incid/bayes")
library(bsts)
library(mcmc)

#simulate some data

y<-rep(NA,50)

y[1]=1
y[2]=1
s=2
set.seed(5)
for (k in 1:48)
{
y[2+k]=y[1+k]+0.1*y[k]+s*rnorm(1)
}
plot(1:50,y[1:50],main=paste("seed =",5))

#bsts model

ss<-AddLocalLevel(list(),y)
mod1<-bsts(y,state.specification=ss,niter=1000)
plot(mod1)

#what is actually being plotted?
#reproduce the plot using mod1$state.contributions

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(1:50,y,col="blue",ylim=c(-12,8),main="quantiles of mod1$state.contributions")
for (i in 1:99)
{
qi<-qin<-rep(NA,50)
tj<-1:50
for (j in 1:50)
{
qi[j]<-quantile(mod1$state.con[501:1000,1,j],(i-0.5)/100)
qin[j]<-quantile(mod1$state.con[501:1000,1,j],(i+1-0.5)/100)
}
polygon(c(tj,rev(tj)),c(qi[1:50],rev(qin[1:50])),col=rgb(0,0,0,40*dnorm(i,mean=50,sd=20)),border=FALSE)
}
plot(mod1,ylim=c(-12,8),main="plot(mod1)")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))

#the state specification is based on sd(y)

sd(y)
ss

#kalman iteration, then add P error term when generating state from xe
#set P[1,,] = 1 to start
#then at end, reset P[1,,]=P[2,,]
#polygon shading

ax<-(mod1$sigma.level[501:1000])^2
bx<-(mod1$sigma.obs[501:1000])^2

state<-matrix(NA,500,50)

for (j in 1:500)
{
a<-ax[j]
b<-bx[j]

H=matrix(1,1,1)
F=matrix(1,1,1)
N=50
dim(y)=c(1,N)

xe<-ye<-ze<-matrix(NA,1,N)
xe[,1]<-1
ye[,1]<-H%*%xe[,1]
ze[,1]<-y[,1]-ye[,1]

P<-K<-array(data=NA,dim=c(N,1,1))
P[1,,]<-1
for (i in 1:(N-1))
{
P[i+1,,]<-F%*%P[i,,]%*%t(F)+a
K[i+1,,]<-P[i+1,,]%*%t(H)%*%solve(b+H%*%P[i+1,,]%*%t(H))
P[i+1,,]<-(diag(1,1)-K[i+1,,]%*%H)%*%P[i+1,,]
xe[1,i+1]<-F%*%xe[,i]+K[i+1,,]%*%(y[,i+1]-H%*%F%*%xe[,i])
}

P[1,,]<-P[2,,]
state[j,]<-rnorm(N,xe[1,1:N],P[1:N,,]^0.5)
}

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(1:N,y,col="blue",ylim=c(-12,8),main="quantiles of kalman state")
for (i in 1:99)
{
qi<-qin<-rep(NA,N)
tj<-1:N
for (k in 1:N)
{
qi[k]<-quantile(state[,k],(i-0.5)/100)
qin[k]<-quantile(state[,k],(i+1-0.5)/100)
}
polygon(c(tj,rev(tj)),c(qi[1:N],rev(qin[1:N])),col=rgb(0,0,0,40*dnorm(i,mean=50,sd=20)),border=FALSE)
}
plot(mod1,ylim=c(-12,8))
par(mfrow=c(1,1))

#indices chosen at random
#plausible that state[,i] and mod1$state.con[501:1000,1,i] are the same distribution

par(mfrow=c(2,4),mar=c(5,5,3,1))
sami<-sample(1:50,8,replace=F)
for (i in 1:8)
{
qqplot(state[,sami[i]],mod1$state.con[501:1000,1,sami[i]],cex=0.5,main=paste("i =",sami[i]),cex.lab=1.3,xlab=paste("state[,",sami[i],"]",sep=""),ylab=paste("mod1$state.con[501:1000,1,",sami[i],"]",sep=""))
lines(state[,sami[i]],state[,sami[i]],col="red")
}
par(mfrow=c(1,1))

#the likelihood, using the kalman filter, as a function of the error variances and the initial state

kal<-function(par)
{
a<-par[1]
b<-par[2]
init<-par[3]
initP<-par[4]

H=matrix(1,1,1)
F=matrix(1,1,1)
#1-dimensional state
N=50
dim(y)=c(1,N)

xe<-ye<-matrix(NA,1,N)
xe[,1]<-init
ye[,1]<-H%*%xe[,1]

P<-K<-array(data=NA,dim=c(N,1,1))
#P[1,,] initial guess
P[1,,]<-initP

for (i in 1:(N-1))
{
P[i+1,,]<-F%*%P[i,,]%*%t(F)+a
K[i+1,,]<-P[i+1,,]%*%t(H)%*%solve(b+H%*%P[i+1,,]%*%t(H))
xe[1,i+1]<-F%*%xe[,i]+K[i+1,,]%*%(y[,i+1]-H%*%F%*%xe[,i])
P[i+1,,]<-(diag(1,1)-K[i+1,,]%*%H)%*%P[i+1,,]
}

-1/2*(log(abs(b))+(1/b)*sum((y[1,]-xe[1,])^2))
}


#independent priors on a and b
#bsts uses sd(y) to set both priors. 
#for a (ss[[1]]$sigma.prior) it uses SdPrior with
#$prior.guess 0.04600655, $prior.df 0.01, $initial.value 0.04600655, $upper.limit 4.600655
#for b (mod1$prior) it uses SdPrior with
#$prior.guess 4.600655, $prior.df 0.01, $initial.value 4.600655, $upper.limit 5.520786
#ss[[1]]$initial.state.prior is normal with mu=1, sd=4.600655

#try an inverse gamma prior on a and b, normal prior on init, with initP fixed

initP<-0.25

lpr1<-function(a)
{
v=0.01
ifelse((a<=0)|a>(sd(y))^2,-Inf,-(v/2+1)*log(a)-v*(sd(y)/100)^2/(2*a))
}

lpr2<-function(b)
{
v=0.01
ifelse((b<=0)|b>(1.2*sd(y))^2,-Inf,-(v/2+1)*log(b)-v*(sd(y))^2/(2*b))
}

lpr3<-function(c)
{
-1/(2*sd(y))*(c-1)^2
}

lpost1<-function(par)
{
a<-par[1]
b<-par[2]
init<-par[3]
lpr1(a)+lpr2(b)+lpr3(init)+kal(c(par,initP))
}

par0<-c(sd(y)/100,sd(y),1)

nb=5000
out<-metrop(lpost1,par0,nb,scale=0.5)
sam<-out$batch
dim(sam)
print(sam[500:510,],12)
par(mfrow=c(3,1))
plot(sam[(nb/2):nb,1],type="l")
plot(sam[(nb/2):nb,2],type="l")
plot(sam[(nb/2):nb,3],type="l")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))

op<-optim(par0,lpost1,control=list(fnscale=-1))
out<-metrop(lpost1,op$par,nb,scale=1)
sam<-out$batch
dim(sam)
print(sam[500:510,],12)
par(mfrow=c(3,1))
plot(sam[(nb/2):nb,1],type="l")
plot(sam[(nb/2):nb,2],type="l")
plot(sam[(nb/2):nb,3],type="l")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))

mpar<-apply(sam[(nb/2):nb,],2,mean)

lpost1m<-function(par) lpost1(par+mpar)
opm<-optim(par0,lpost1m,control=list(fnscale=-1))

#a little fiddling gets plausible mixing
nb=5000
#be patient
outm<-metrop(lpost1m,opm$par,nb,blen=5,nspac=10,scale=1.5)
outm$acc
samm<-outm$batch
dim(samm)
par(mfrow=c(3,1))
plot(samm[(nb/2):nb,1],type="l")
plot(samm[(nb/2):nb,2],type="l")
plot(samm[(nb/2):nb,3],type="l")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
acf(samm)
samm<-thin(samm,5)
dim(samm)
acf(samm)
print(samm[501:510,],8)
par(mfrow=c(3,1))
plot(samm[501:1000,1],type="l")
plot(samm[501:1000,2],type="l")
plot(samm[501:1000,3],type="l")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))

#plot kalman using samm from lpost1m

ax<-samm[501:1000,1]+mpar[1]
bx<-samm[501:1000,2]+mpar[2]
initx<-samm[501:1000,3]+mpar[3]

state<-matrix(NA,500,50)

for (j in 1:500)
{
a<-ax[j]
b<-bx[j]
init<-initx[j]

H=matrix(1,1,1)
F=matrix(1,1,1)
N=50
dim(y)=c(1,N)

xe<-ye<-matrix(NA,1,N)
xe[,1]<-init
ye[,1]<-H%*%xe[,1]

P<-K<-array(data=NA,dim=c(N,1,1))
P[1,,]<-0
for (i in 1:(N-1))
{
P[i+1,,]<-F%*%P[i,,]%*%t(F)+a
K[i+1,,]<-P[i+1,,]%*%t(H)%*%solve(b+H%*%P[i+1,,]%*%t(H))
P[i+1,,]<-(diag(1,1)-K[i+1,,]%*%H)%*%P[i+1,,]
xe[1,i+1]<-F%*%xe[,i]+K[i+1,,]%*%(y[,i+1]-H%*%F%*%xe[,i])
}

P[1,,]<-P[2,,]
state[j,]<-rnorm(N,xe[1,1:N],P[1:N,,]^0.5)
}

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(1:N,y,col="blue",ylim=c(-12,8))
for (i in 1:99)
{
qi<-qin<-rep(NA,N)
tj<-1:N
for (k in 1:N)
{
qi[k]<-quantile(state[,k],(i-0.5)/100)
qin[k]<-quantile(state[,k],(i+1-0.5)/100)
}
polygon(c(tj,rev(tj)),c(qi[1:N],rev(qin[1:N])),col=rgb(0,0,0,35*dnorm(i,mean=50,sd=15)),border=FALSE)
}
plot(mod1,ylim=c(-12,8))
par(mfrow=c(1,1))

#plausible
#but

mean(ax)
mean((mod1$sigma.level[501:1000])^2)
qqplot(ax,(mod1$sigma.level[501:1000])^2)

mean(bx)
mean((mod1$sigma.obs[501:1000])^2)
qqplot(bx,(mod1$sigma.obs[501:1000])^2)
lines(bx,bx,col="red")

#so ax is not sampling (sigma.level)^2
#bx not sampling (sigma.obs)^2
```

Answer (score 0):

somewhat improved now, mainly by altering the maximum values in the priors.

The posterior means are much closer to the bsts output, but the distributions still differ. I can't tell what implementation of mcmc is being used in bsts.

Greg

### #

```
setwd("/home/greg/Documents/rwork/incid/bayes")
library(bsts)
library(mcmc)
library(coda)

#simulate some data

y<-rep(NA,50)

y[1]=1
y[2]=1
s=2
set.seed(5)
for (k in 1:48)
{
y[2+k]=y[1+k]+0.1*y[k]+s*rnorm(1)
}
plot(1:50,y[1:50],main=paste("seed =",5))

#bsts model

ss<-AddLocalLevel(list(),y)
mod1<-bsts(y,state.specification=ss,niter=5000)
plot(mod1)

#has mod1 converged?
sigmc<-as.mcmc(cbind(mod1$sigma.level,mod1$sigma.obs))
plot(sigmc)
acf(sigmc)
#highly correlated
heidel.diag(sigmc)
geweke.plot(sigmc)
#looks ok

#skipping the discussion of what is being plotted

#the likelihood, using the kalman filter, as a function of the error variances and the initial state

kal<-function(par)
{
a<-par[1]
b<-par[2]
init<-par[3]

H=matrix(1,1,1)
F=matrix(1,1,1)
#1-dimensional state
N=50
dim(y)=c(1,N)

xe<-ye<-matrix(NA,1,N)
xe[,1]<-init
ye[,1]<-H%*%xe[,1]

P<-K<-array(data=NA,dim=c(N,1,1))
#P[1,,] initial guess
P[1,,]<-b

for (i in 1:(N-1))
{
P[i+1,,]<-F%*%P[i,,]%*%t(F)+a
K[i+1,,]<-P[i+1,,]%*%t(H)%*%solve(b+H%*%P[i+1,,]%*%t(H))
xe[1,i+1]<-F%*%xe[,i]+K[i+1,,]%*%(y[,i+1]-H%*%F%*%xe[,i])
P[i+1,,]<-(diag(1,1)-K[i+1,,]%*%H)%*%P[i+1,,]
}

-1/2*(log(abs(b))+(1/b)*sum((y[1,]-xe[1,])^2))
}


#priors

lpr1<-function(a)
{
v=0.01
ifelse((a<=0)|a>sd(y),-Inf,-(v/2+1)*log(a)-v*(sd(y)/100)^2/(2*a))
}

lpr2<-function(b)
{
v=0.01
ifelse((b<=0)|b>1.2*sd(y),-Inf,-(v/2+1)*log(b)-v*(sd(y))^2/(2*b))
}

lpr3<-function(c)
{
-1/(2*(sd(y))^2)*(c-1)^2
}

lpost1<-function(par)
{
a<-par[1]
b<-par[2]
init<-par[3]
lpr1(a)+lpr2(b)+lpr3(init)+kal(par)
}

par0<-c(sd(y)/100,sd(y),1)

nb=5000
out<-metrop(lpost1,par0,nb,blen=5,nspac=5,scale=0.3)
out$acc
sam<-out$batch
samc<-as.mcmc(sam)
plot(samc)
heidel.diag(samc)
geweke.plot(samc)
acf(samc)

#plot kalman using samc

ax<-samc[2501:5000,1]
bx<-samc[2501:5000,2]
initx<-samc[2501:5000,3]

state<-matrix(NA,2500,50)

for (j in 1:2500)
{
a<-ax[j]
b<-bx[j]
init<-initx[j]

H=matrix(1,1,1)
F=matrix(1,1,1)
N=50
dim(y)=c(1,N)

xe<-ye<-matrix(NA,1,N)
xe[,1]<-init
ye[,1]<-H%*%xe[,1]

P<-K<-array(data=NA,dim=c(N,1,1))
P[1,,]<-b
for (i in 1:(N-1))
{
P[i+1,,]<-F%*%P[i,,]%*%t(F)+a
K[i+1,,]<-P[i+1,,]%*%t(H)%*%solve(b+H%*%P[i+1,,]%*%t(H))
P[i+1,,]<-(diag(1,1)-K[i+1,,]%*%H)%*%P[i+1,,]
xe[1,i+1]<-F%*%xe[,i]+K[i+1,,]%*%(y[,i+1]-H%*%F%*%xe[,i])
}

state[j,]<-rnorm(N,xe[1,1:N],P[1:N,,]^0.5)
}

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(1:N,y,col="blue",ylim=c(-12,8))
for (i in 1:99)
{
qi<-qin<-rep(NA,N)
tj<-1:N
for (k in 1:N)
{
qi[k]<-quantile(state[,k],(i-0.5)/100)
qin[k]<-quantile(state[,k],(i+1-0.5)/100)
}
polygon(c(tj,rev(tj)),c(qi[1:N],rev(qin[1:N])),col=rgb(0,0,0,40*dnorm(i,mean=50,sd=20)),border=FALSE)
}
plot(mod1,ylim=c(-12,8))
par(mfrow=c(1,1))

#plausible
#but

mean(ax^0.5)
mean(mod1$sigma.level[2501:5000])
#better
qqplot(ax^0.5,mod1$sigma.level[2501:5000])
lines(ax^0.5,ax^0.5,col="red")

mean(bx^0.5)
mean(mod1$sigma.obs[501:1000])
qqplot(bx^0.5,mod1$sigma.obs[501:1000])
lines(bx^0.5,bx^0.5,col="red")

#so ax^0.5 is still not sampling sigma.level
#bx^0.5 still not sampling sigma.obs
```